# R: Encode character variables into numeric

Tags: r, encoding, character

In R code I have a character variable `var` that has values "AA", "AB", "AC", etc.

```
str(var)
chr [1:17003] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AB" "AB" ...
```

How can I convert it to numeric variable so that "AA" would be coded as, e.g. 1, "AB" - as 2, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the string to a factor and then to numeric.

```
x <- c("AA", "AB", "AB", "AC", "AA", "XY")
as.numeric(as.factor(x))
# [1] 1 2 2 3 1 4
```

Alternatively, you can use `match` and `unique`:

```
match(x, unique(x))
# [1] 1 2 2 3 1 4
```

Answer (score 4):

> you can use them by directly converting them into factors with labeling.

```
x$Country = factor(x$Country,
               levels = c('AA', 'AB', 'AC'),
               labels = c(1, 2, 3))
```