# Recoding strings to numerical codes

Tags: r

I'm at an beginner/intermediary R-Level and have most of my experience in Stata. I have a problem I easily could solve in Stata, to which I have no clue in R. I think I have searched this forum in due dilligence.

I have a string variable containing codes for unique persons.

```
data$unique
[1] ABC1500
[2] DEF1500
[3] GH1500
```

I need these codes to become numerical, so I can use them in an analysis. In Stata I would use

```
encode unique, gen(newname)
```

and get a numerical value for each unique person in my data. In Stata these new values would also be labeled. I would like to avoid inputting these new data in R, as I have thousands of persons to code.

I can't find a similar function in R.

Any suggestions?

Andreas

Comment: See `?factor`, most likely the variable is already stored as a `factor` variable, so you are good to go for analysis. You can check this and  other useful information with `str(myDataSetName)`. Note that factor variables are integers with labels, essentially the same thing as `encode` in Stata or the ever helpful `egen ... group()`.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764983/r-encode-character-variables-into-numeric

Comment: `data$unique = factor(data$unique)` is all you need. They will be encoded under the hood as integer, but will be printed with their label. (There's a strong possibility your data is *already* a factor, many ways of reading in data default to factor rather than string. Check the current class with `class(data$unique)`.)