# How to assign values to string when the data is very large R

Tags: r

How to assign values to string when the data is very large.

Currently I assign values to character vectors manually as illustrated below, however, when the amount of data is very large it becomes tedious to do that process manually. Is there a function that allows me to do it?

```
c("a" = 100, "b" = 200, "c"=300, ..., "aaaaaa" = n)
```

Comment: yes, the function is called `setNames`.  used as  `setNames(your_vector, your_names)`

Comment: Thank you very much. There is definitely a function for everything!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular meaning to your numbering?  If you just need numerical values for strings, you can use `as.factor` and `as.numeric` as outlined in this post:

[R: Encode character variables into numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764983/r-encode-character-variables-into-numeric)

However, if you need a specific encoding you will have specify the associated `labels` necessary; there isn't enough information in your question to help with this further, but the documentation is here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor